# Zoom CollectionView inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, collectionview, zoom-sdk

I want to zoom a collectionView inside a scrollView, but when I zoom the scrollView, the contentOffset of the scrollView doesn't change. Therefore, I can't scroll to the top of the collectionView when zoomed. How can I address this situation? I want to smoothly zoom and scroll, similar to reading a PDF.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    static let cellId = "CellId"

    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)



        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.view.frame.size), collectionViewLayout: layout)

        collectionView!.register(ZoomableCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "singleCell")
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView!)
        scrollView!.addSubview(collectionView!)
        scrollView!.delegate = self
        scrollView!.maximumZoomScale = 3
        let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapGesture(_:)))
        doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        collectionView!.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)

    }
    @objc
    private func doubleTapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if ( self.scrollView!.zoomScale > 1.0) {
            self.scrollView!.setZoomScale(1.0, animated: true)
        } else {
            let zoomRect:CGRect = self.zoomRectForScale(scale: 3.0 / 2 , center: sender.location(in: sender.view))
            self.scrollView!.zoom(to: zoomRect, animated: true)
        }

    }

    func zoomRectForScale(scale:CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect{
        var zoomRect: CGRect = CGRect()
        // this point (center) is relative to collection view, need convert back to contentView
        let contentW = view.frame.width
        let contentH = view.frame.height
        let newX = center.x - contentW * floor(center.x / contentW)
        let newPoint = CGPoint(x: newX, y: center.y)
        zoomRect.size.height = contentH / scale
        zoomRect.size.width = contentW / scale
        zoomRect.origin.x = newPoint.x - zoomRect.size.width / 2.0
        zoomRect.origin.y = newPoint.y - zoomRect.size.height / 2.0
        return zoomRect
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:ZoomableCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "singleCell", for: indexPath) as! ZoomableCell

        let image = UIImage(named:"test")
        cell.imageView.image = image
        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return collectionView
    }
}

class ZoomableCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var imageView:UIImageView!

    required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect){
        super.init(frame:frame)

        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        //imageViewを生成
        imageView =  UIImageView()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.frame.width,height:self.frame.height)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that your collection view is consuming the vertical drag gesture. Notice that when you cannot scroll to the top, if you start dragging horizontally - even just a little - and then continue dragging down, you *will* get to the top. Is your goal to zoom/pan on a single image (one cell), and then zoom back out to the collection view? Or, do you need to zoom/pan the entire collection view?

Comment: Yes, if i dragging horrizontally, then continue dragging down/up, i will get to the top. I need to zoom/pan the entire collectionview

Comment: That's going to be difficult, because you have conflicting scroll views (the scrollView and the collection view's internal scroll view). Your example code shows 10 items (image) ... are you going to potentially have (many) more than that?

Comment: Yes, I have about 15 to 30 images